# Is there anyway I can boost my stats?

Tags: nhl-15

I am currently playing the Pro Mode (Player created Career) in NHL '15.  I have already played roughly 10 games, but my growth in stats is **very very slow**.  It takes roughly 2 games to earn enough points to spend on one stat per category (4-7 stats per category).  Is there anyway to speed this up?  I have turned the difficulty up from Rookie to Pro and increased the time of the games from 5 minutes to 10 minutes, but this only slightly increased the points rewarded after each game I play.